# Multiple column sorting and arraging algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm

#### Problem

The goal is to perform the following transformation:

[image]

Additionally, if two rows can be merged, they are combined into one:

[image]

#### Code

I wrote the following algorithm to solve this problem:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using Matrix = std::vector<std::vector<int>>;
using Column = std::vector<int>;

Column max_col(const Matrix &v) {
    return *std::max_element(v.begin(), v.end(),
                             [](auto& lhs, auto& rhs)
                             {
                                 return lhs.size() < rhs.size();
                             });
}

bool is_element_in_next_rows(const Matrix &v, int element,int row) {
    for (auto& col : v) {
        if (row >= static_cast<int>(col.size())) continue; // out of range
        if (std::lower_bound(col.begin()+row+1,col.end(),element) != 
            std::upper_bound(col.begin()+row+1,col.end(),element)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

int min_element_in_row(const Matrix &v, int row) { 
    int min_element = max_col(v)[row];
    for (auto& col : v) {
        if (row >= static_cast<int>(col.size())) continue; // out of range
        if (col[row] != 0) min_element = std::min(min_element, col[row]);
    }
    return min_element;
}

void print_elements(const Matrix &v) {
    for (auto& i : v) {
        for (auto& j : i) {
            std::cout << j << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

void organize_elements(Matrix &v) {
    for (auto& col : v) {
        std::sort(col.begin(),col.end());
    }
    auto current_max_col = max_col(v);
    for (int row{0}; current_max_col.begin()+row!=current_max_col.end(); ++row) {
        int min_element = min_element_in_row(v,row);
        for(auto& col : v) {
            if (row >= static_cast<int>(col.size())) continue; // out of range
            int candidate = col[row];
            if (candidate > min_element) {
                if (is_element_in_next_rows(v,candidate,row)) {
                    col.push_back(0);
                    std::rotate(col.begin()+row,col.end()-1,col.end());
                }
            }
        }
        current_max_col = max_col(v);
    }
}

int main() {

    Column c1 = {5,6,8,11};
    Column c2 = {2,5,3,1,4,6};
    Column c3 = {8,7,2,4,5,3,1};

    Matrix v;
    v.push_back(c1);
    v.push_back(c2);
    v.push_back(c3);

    std::cout << "original: \n";
    print_elements(v);
    organize_elements(v);
    std::cout << "organized: \n";
    print_elements(v);
    return 0;
}
```

Which produces the following output:

```
original: 
5 6 8 11 
2 5 3 1 4 6 
8 7 2 4 5 3 1 
organized: 
0 0 0 0 5 6 8 11 
1 2 3 4 5 6 
1 2 3 4 5 7 8
```

#### Questions

I particularly don't like this part of my code:

```
auto current_max_col = max_col(v);
for (int row{0}; current_max_col.begin()+row!=current_max_col.end(); ++row) {
    // ....
    current_max_col = max_col(v);
}
```

I also don't like that I have to do this cast:

```
if (row >= static_cast<int>(col.size())) continue; // out of range
```

Is there a way to do this check better?

The fact that I need to declare `current_max_col` out of the `for`, and then update it inside the loop. Any idea how to avoid this?

Any other ideas about how to solve this problem? Any other tips? Thank you!

Comment: In your examples one column contains the entire range `[1..8]` and no other value exceeds `8`. Is there some hidden restriction (otherwise, `max_col` looks suspicious)?

Comment: @vnp There are no other restrictions. I've changed the example, not sure if it's clearer now.

Comment: It is clearer. You may want to edit the introductory examples as well.

Comment: @vnp Great, done ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you can leverage the stl algorithms better. There are still too many *raw loops* in your code...

I understand why you fell in love with `std::rotate` but it isn't the only tool at your disposal.

For instance, `std::min_element` is flexible enough to handle the `min_element_in_row`:

```
int row_minimum(const Matrix& m, std::size_t row) {
    return std::min_element(m.begin(), m.end(), [row](auto&& lhs, auto&& rhs) {
            if (row < lhs.size()) {
                if (row < rhs.size()) return lhs[row] < rhs[row];
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        })->at(row);
}
```

Also, there is no need to compare the results of `std::lower_bound` and `std::upper_bound`. You know that the element is in the range if `*std::lower_bound(b, e,  elem) == elem`, because it returns an iterator to the first element equal to or greater than elem.

That said, here's my suggestion (I'm not handling row combinations though):

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>

void normalize_columns(Matrix& m) {
    for (auto& col : m) std::sort(col.begin(), col.end());
    // build a 'synthetized' column by merging columns and removing duplicates
    Column merger;
    for (const auto& col : m) {
        Column tmp;
        std::merge(col.begin(), col.end(), merger.begin(), merger.end(), std::back_inserter(tmp));
        std::swap(tmp, merger);
    }
    auto uniques = std::unique(merger.begin(), merger.end());
    // replace each column by a copy of the synthetized column 
    //from which all elements not included in the original column are replaced by 0
    for (auto& col : m) {
        Column normalized;
        std::replace_copy_if(merger.begin(), uniques, std::back_inserter(normalized),
                             [&col](auto&& elem) { 
                                 return *std::lower_bound(col.begin(), col.end(), elem) != elem; 
                             }, 0);
        std::swap(col, normalized);
    }
}

int main() {

    Column c1 = {5,6,8,11};
    Column c2 = {2,5,3,1,4,6};
    Column c3 = {8,7,2,4,5,3,1};

    Matrix m{c1, c2, c3};

    normalize_columns(m);
    for (auto& col : m) {
        for (auto elem : col) std::cout << elem << ' ';
        std::cout << '\n';
    }

}
```

The output is slightly different from yours but seems to fit the problem specification:

```
0 0 0 0 5 6 0 8 11    
1 2 3 4 5 6 0 0 0 
1 2 3 4 5 0 7 8 0
```

Comment: Love it! Very inspiring. You are very right, I'm still getting to know the algorithms. Little by little! Thank you again

Comment: I'm not sure with your code how to tackle the part of merging columns when they fit.  `0  6 6` followed by `7 0 0` should be combined in `7 6 6`

Comment: Not sure if it is possible to do without resorting to custom loops. A `std::reduce` would do the trick if a "row-iterator" was available. I believe it fair to describe this `Matrix` class as bare-bone. More elegant code would need a stronger foundation to build upon.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the transform you are after is a `k`-way merge in disguise.

In the nutshell, set up a min-heap of pairs `<col_id, vector<int>::iterator>`. On each iteration construct a vector of values equal to heap head, 0 otherwise; push it to the resulting matrix; remove those entries from heap an pull new values from the respective columns. Sorry if I miss something obvious.

I don't think you shall strive for in-place transform.

---

I am pretty sure that merging rows deserve a separate pass.

---

The

```
                col.push_back(0);
                std::rotate(col.begin()+row,col.end()-1,col.end());
```

is no better than `col.insert(col.begin() + row, 0);`

---

The `static_cast<int>(col.size())` suggests that `row` should not be `int`, but along the lines of `std::vector<int>::size_type`.

Comment: Interesting, I don't quite get it though. I'll try to implement it and see if I got it right.

Comment: I don't get it, what you mean with _construct a vector of values equal to heap head_. Could you give me an idea of how the code would look like?